# Area of self-intersecting polygon

Tags: algorithm, svg, 2d, polygon

Calculating the area of a *simple irregular* polygon [is trivial](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html). However, consider the self-intersecting polygon ABCDEF shown at left below:

[image: A self-intersecting polygon shaped like a 'figure 8']

If we use the linked-to formula above traversing the points in polygon order, we get an area of 0. (The 'clockwise' area cancels out the 'counter-clockwise' area.)

However, if we [sort the points radially around a center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order) and calculate the area, we get the incorrect area of the polygon ABEDCF at right above.

How can I best find the visible area of a self-intersecting polygon? (If the answer requires creating phantom points for each intersection, please provide details for how to best find the intersections and how then to traverse them in correct order.)

*This question arose when investigating edge cases for my solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10045537/405017).*

### Defining the Area

I define the 'area' as the amount of pixels visible when filling the polygon using either the "nonzero" or "evenodd" rules. I will accept an answer for either of these, though both would be better. Note that I explicitly do *not* define the area for self-overlapping to count the overlapping area twice.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have hole in your polygon?

Comment: Perhaps `0` is the correct answer :)

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "area" in case of self-intersecting polygon. How do you define the interior? The example you have above is too simplistic to be sufficient. In more complicated cases it is simply not clear what is part of the "area" and what is not. Until you come up with a meaningful definition, there's no sense in trying to find the answer.

Comment: @AndreyT It seems, this is a 2d question and area is an expression to used for an enclosed surface..

Comment: @AndreyT By "area" I mean the amount of paint visible when filling the polygon. Take your pick as to whether overlapping strokes are treated as either [evenodd or nonzero](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html); the answer is the same for the above, and both answers would be useful.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I'm not sure what you mean by a 'hole'. I consider a polygon to be a single connected edge, not one edge with another discontiguous 'subtracted' from the interior. If you mean self-overlapping borders (like the loop [seen here](http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml)) filled using an evenodd rule (which would make that loop a 'hole'), then that is possible. As noted above, I would appreciate an answer that either used evenodd or one that used nonzero; for nonzero, however, the area calculation should not count the overlapping region twice.

Comment: I'm sure you've found a solution since, but for future readers, [this solution might be an interesting starting point](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47640/8478).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [Bentley–Ottmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) with the following pseudo code from [this page](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm)

**The Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm**

The input for the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm is a collection OMEGA={Li} of line segments Li, and its output will be a set LAMBDA={Ij} of intersection points. This algorithm is referred to as a "sweep line algorithm" because it's operation can be visualized as having another line, a "sweep line" SL, sweeping over the collection OMEGA and collecting information as it passes over the individual segments Li. The information collected for each position of SL is basically an ordered list of all segments in OMEGA that are currently being intersected by SL. The data structure maintaining this information is often also called the "sweep line". This class structure also detects and outputs intersections as it discovers them. The process by which it discovers intersections is the heart of the algorithm and its efficiency.

To implement the sweep logic, we must first linearly order the segments of OMEGA to determine the sequence in which SL encounters them. That is, we need to order the endpoints {Ei0,Ei1}i=1,n of all the segments Li so we can detect when SL starts and stops intersecting each segment of OMEGA. Traditionally, the endpoints are ordered by increasing x first and then increasing y-coordinate values, but any linear order will do (some authors prefer decreasing y first and then increasing x). With the traditional ordering, the sweep line is vertical and moves from left to right as it encounters each segment, as shown in the diagram:

Pic-sweepline

At any point in the algorithm, the sweep line SL intersects only those segments with one endpoint to the left of (or on) it and the other endpoint to the right of it. The SL data structure keeps a dynamic list of these segments by: (1) adding a segment when its leftmost endpoint is encountered, and (2) deleting a segment when its rightmost endpoint is encountered. Further, the SL orders the list of segments with an "above-below" relation. So, to add or delete a segment, its position in the list must be determined, which can be done by a worst-case O(log-n) binary search of the current segments in the list. In addition, besides adding or deleting segments, there is another event that changes the list structure; namely, whenever two segments intersect, then their positions in the ordered list must be swapped. Given the two segments, which must be neighbors in the list, this swap is an O(log-n) operation.

To organize all this, the algorithm maintains an ordered "event queue" EQ whose elements cause a change in the SL segment list. Initially, EQ is set to the sweep-ordered list of all segment endpoints. But as intersections between segments are found, then they are also added to EQ in the same sweep-order as used for the endpoints One must test, though, to avoid inserting duplicate intersections onto the event queue. The example in the above diagram shows how this can happen. At event 2, segments S1 and S2 cause intersection I12 to be computed and put on the queue. Then, at event 3, segment S3 comes between and separates S1 and S2. Next, at event 4, S1 and S3 swap places on the sweep line, and S1 is brought next to S2 again causing I12 to be computed again.  But, there can only be one event for each intersection, and I12 cannot be put on the queue twice. So, when an intersection is being put on the queue, we must find its potential x-sorted location in the queue, and check that it is not already there. Since there is at most one intersect point for any two segments, labeling an intersection with identifiers for the segments is sufficient to uniquely identify it. As a result of all this, the maximum size of the event queue = 2n+k.le.2n+n2, and any insertion or deletion can be done with a O(log(2n+n2)) = O(log-n) binary search.

But, what does all this have to do with efficiently finding the complete set of segment intersections? Well, as segments are sequentially added to the SL segment list, their possible intersections with other eligible segments are determined. When a valid intersection is found, then it is inserted into the event queue. Further, when an intersection-event on EQ is processed during the sweep, then it causes a re-ordering of the SL list, and the intersection is also added to the output list LAMBDA. In the end, when all events have been processed, LAMBDA will contain the complete ordered set of all intersections.

However, there is one critical detail, the heart of the algorithm, that we still need to describe; namely, how does one compute a valid intersection? Clearly, two segments can only intersect if they occur simultaneously on the sweep-line at some time. But this by itself is not enough to make the algorithm efficient. The important observation is that two intersecting segments must be immediate above-below neighbors on the sweep-line. Thus, there are only a few restricted cases for which possible intersections need to be computed:

When a segment is added to the SL list, determine if it intersects with its above and below neighbors.

When a segment is deleted from the SL list, its previous above and below neighbors are brought together as new neighbors. So, their possible intersection needs to be determined.

At an intersection event, two segments switch positions in the SL list, and their intersection with their new neighbors (one for each) must be determined.
This means that for the processing of any one event (endpoint or intersection) of EQ, there are at most two intersection determinations that need to be made.

One detail remains, namely the time needed to add, find, swap, and remove segments from the SL structure. To do this, the SL can be implemented as a balanced binary tree (such as an AVL, a 2-3, or a red-black tree) which guarantees that these operations will take at most O(log-n) time since n is the maximum size of the SL list. Thus, each of the (2n+k) events has at worst O(log-n) processing to do. Adding up the initial sort and the event processing, the efficiency of the algorithm is: O(nlog-n)+O((2n+k)log-n)=O((n+k)log-n).

**Pseudo-Code: Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm**

Putting all of this together, the top-level logic for an implementation of the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm is given by the following pseudo-code:

```
    Initialize event queue EQ = all segment endpoints;
    Sort EQ by increasing x and y;
    Initialize sweep line SL to be empty;
    Initialize output intersection list IL to be empty;

    While (EQ is nonempty) {
        Let E = the next event from EQ;
        If (E is a left endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Add segE to SL;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segA) exists) 
                Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segB) exists) 
                Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else If (E is a right endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            Delete segE from SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segA with segB) exists) 
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else {  // E is an intersection event
            Add E’s intersect point to the output list IL;
            Let segE1 above segE2 be E's intersecting segments in SL;
            Swap their positions so that segE2 is now above segE1;
            Let segA = the segment above segE2 in SL;
            Let segB = the segment below segE1 in SL;
            If (I = Intersect(segE2 with segA) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect(segE1 with segB) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        remove E from EQ;
    }
    return IL;
}
```

This routine outputs the complete ordered list of all intersection points.

Comment: That looks very helpful, but it does not fully answer the question. Specifically, imagine that I can find the intersection X for the segments BC and FE above. What do I do then? I need to walk in the order ABXEDCXF, yet how do I properly sort the two occurrences of X to the appropriate two locations?

Comment: No, you should divide your polygon. I mean when you see an intersection, you should create a child polygon and continue as if your original polygon does not have that child any more..After sweeping all the domain, you will end up with a list of child polygons, which form your original polygon when added together..So your original area will be the summation of areas of those child polygons. You may also want to see this valuable book about [computational geometry](http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Computer-Graphics-Morgan-Kaufmann/dp/1558605940)

Comment: The above comment is the right one. The correct way is to split the polygon just the way mr Ozmen describes above. Javascript Clipper http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/ does just that. In the very near future it will also introduce a recursive adaptive subdivision of the beziers to convert them into polygons so curved shapes can be calculated as well, with minimal computational time needs.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained because hyperlinks may go dead in the future.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is from top of my mind, I'd assume there is no hole in your polygon, with hole it will be more complicated and you should first remove holes from your poly:

1. First find convex hull of your polygon, for this you need to find convex hull of your polygon vertices. And compute convex hull area.
2. After that, find all intersection of your polygon.
3. You should subtract extra polygons which doesn't belong to your original polygon from convex hull to find your polygon area, name them *badpoly*. *badpolys* always have at least one border on convex hull, such that this border does not belong to your original polygon, name them *badborder*, by iterating over convex hull you can find all *badborders*, but for finding other borders of *badpoly*, next connected border to given *badborder* which has smallest angle relative to *badborder* is one of a borders of your *badpoly*, you can continue this to find all borders of your *badpoly* and then calulate its area, also by repeating this way you can calculate area of all *badpolys*.

Comment: It seems, this will work too, but ofcouse computation will rise up, because of the all counters and area computations. I will keep this in my mind for similar cases, thanks, nice way of thinking

Answer (score -2):

The Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm is not good in that case.

Because it only works well when you want the intersection-Point between segments.

haha, I have solved the problem to calculate the self-intersecting polygon by transforming the self-intersecting polygon to multi-polygons.

here is my code.

https://github.com/zslzz/intersection_polygon

```
class SdPolygon(object):

  def __init__(self, points=None):
    points = self.parafloat(points)
    self.points = points
    self.current_points = []
    self.sd_polygons = []
    self.gene_polygon()
    from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
    self.sd_polygon = cascaded_union(self.sd_polygons)

  def parafloat(self, points):
    """
    为保证准确，将所有的浮点数转化为整数
    :return:
    """
    para_point = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in points]
    return para_point

  def gene_polygon(self):
    for point in self.points:
        self.add_point_to_current(point)  # 依次将点加入数组
    p0 = Polygon(self.current_points)
    self.sd_polygons.append(p0)

  def add_point_to_current(self, point):
    """
    将该点加入到current_points 中，倒序遍历current_points中的点，如果能围成多边形，则将所围成的点弹出
    :param point:
    :return:
    """
    if len(self.current_points) < 2:
        self.current_points.append(point)
        return
    cross_point_dict = {}  # 记录线段与其他点的相交点，{0:P1,6:P2}
    l0 = Line(Point(point[0], point[1]), Point(self.current_points[-1][0], self.current_points[-1][1]))
    for i in range(0, len(self.current_points) - 1):
        line = Line(Point(self.current_points[i][0], self.current_points[i][1]),
                    Point(self.current_points[i + 1][0], self.current_points[i + 1][1]))
        cross_point = self.get_cross_point(l0, line)  # 获取相交点
        if self.is_in_two_segment(cross_point, l0, line):  # 如果相交点在两个线段上
            cross_point_dict.update({i: cross_point})
    flag_dict = {}  # 保存剪下点的信息
    cross_points_list = sorted(cross_point_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)  # [(3,P),(1,P)]
    for cross_point_info in cross_points_list:
        cross_i, cross_point = cross_point_info[0], cross_point_info[1]
        if flag_dict:  # 对应需要剪下多个多边形的情形，
            points = self.current_points[cross_i + 1:flag_dict['index'] + 1]
            points.append((flag_dict['point'].x, flag_dict['point'].y))
            points.append((cross_point.x, cross_point.y))
            p = Polygon(points)
            self.sd_polygons.append(p)
        else:
            points = self.current_points[cross_i + 1:]
            points.append((cross_point.x, cross_point.y))
            p = Polygon(points)
            self.sd_polygons.append(p)  # 将生成的polygon保存
        flag_dict.update(index=cross_i, point=cross_point)
    if flag_dict:
        point_list = self.current_points[:flag_dict['index'] + 1]  # 还未围成多边形的数组
        point_list.append((flag_dict['point'].x, flag_dict['point'].y))  # 加上交点
        self.current_points = point_list
    self.current_points.append(point)

  def is_in_segment(self, point, point1, point2):
    """
    交点是否在线段上
    :param point:(x,y)
    :param point1:[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
    :param point2:
    :return:
    """
    if point1.x > point2.x:
        minx = point2.x
        maxx = point1.x
    else:
        minx = point1.x
        maxx = point2.x
    if point1.y > point2.y:
        miny = point2.y
        maxy = point1.y
    else:
        miny = point1.y
        maxy = point2.y
    if minx <= point.x <= maxx and miny <= point.y <= maxy:
        return True
    return False

  def is_in_two_segment(self, point, l1, l2):
    """
    点 是否在两段 线段中间
    :param point:
    :param l1:
    :param l2:
    :return:
    """

    def is_same_point(p1, p2):
        """
        判断点是否相同
        :param p1:
        :param p2:
        :return:
        """
        if abs(p1.x - p2.x) < 0.1 and abs(p1.y - p2.y) < 0.1:
            return True
        return False

    if self.is_in_segment(point, l1.p1, l1.p2) and self.is_in_segment(point, l2.p1, l2.p2):
        if (is_same_point(point, l1.p1) or is_same_point(point, l1.p2)) and (
                    is_same_point(point, l2.p1) or is_same_point(point, l2.p2)):
            # 判断是否在两条线段的端点上
            return False
        return True
    return False

  def get_line_para(self, line):
    """
    规整line
    :param line:
    :return:
    """
    line.a = line.p1.y - line.p2.y
    line.b = line.p2.x - line.p1.x
    line.c = line.p1.x * line.p2.y - line.p2.x * line.p1.y

  def get_cross_point(self, l1, l2):
    """
    得到交点
    :param l1: 直线Line
    :param l2:
    :return: 交点坐标Point
    """
    self.get_line_para(l1)
    self.get_line_para(l2)
    d = l1.a * l2.b - l2.a * l1.b
    p = Point()
    if d == 0:
        return p
    p.x = ((l1.b * l2.c - l2.b * l1.c) // d)
    p.y = ((l1.c * l2.a - l2.c * l1.a) // d)
    return p
```