# How to calculate the Area of a SVG 'Path' element in Java ?

Tags: java, svg, path, batik

Is there any function or library available in Java to calculate the area of SVG Path element. I have search around and found few implementation [[How can I calculate the area of a bezier curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039679/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-bezier-curve) ] but these implementations are in JavaScript. Is there any implementation in Java for calculating the area of Path element. Thanks...